Sum of the elements present in an array
//Adding all the Elements in an array and displaying their sum
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of Elements in an array: ";
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[n];
    }
    int sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += a[n];
    }
    cout << sum;
}

Output:
Enter the number of Elements in an array: 2
1
5
10

I replaced 'i' with 'n' but still wasn't able to get the desired output. I was expecting that i would get the sum of all the elements of the array.

You must initialize sum to zero, otherwise you have undefined behavior. It could contain any value. int sum = 0; And change back to sum+=a[i]; -- guessing at code changes is only gonna cause more problems.

Use std::accumulate instead.

Before you make a change like replacing i with n sit down and talk it through with your rubber duck. Now, your average rubber duckies are notoriously slow, so you have to explain what you are doing and what you expect to happen to them very carefully. Often drawing pictures helps. If the duck understands and agrees with your plan, follow through with it. If not. it's probably not going to work.

Three issues are present in your code:

sum is uninitialized, so adding to it results in undefined behavior because without being initialized the value is indeterminate. Initializing might look like int sum = 0; or even just int sum {}; which default initializes to zero.
In your loops, you need to access a[i] rather than a[n]. Since arrays are indexed starting at zero, the max index for a is n-1, so a[n] is an out of bounds access and again... undefined behavior.
Variable length arrays (VLAs) are not a standard part of C++. Use std::vector instead when you want to create an array where the bounds are not known at compile time.

As a suggestion, using namespace std; is not encouraged. You'll also want to get in the habit of verifying that user input succeeded.

Here's the solution
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of Elements in an array: ";
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i]; // i instead of n
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += a[i]; // i instead of n
    }
    cout << "Sum: " << sum;
    return 0;
}


This would be better if it identified the issues (your comments have not covered the initialization of sum) rather than simply offering a solution, and if it didn't use non-standard VLAs nor using namespace std;.

and after learning the basics you should use std::accumulate instead of manually summing like this

This is a code-only answer, and those tend to produce Cargo Cult Programmers, something the world already has in surplus, rather than useful problem-solvers.
